# javascript prototype constructor confusion

Tags: javascript

```
function Test()
{
    this.name = 'test name';
}


console.log(Test.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor);
```

I can't understand why is this a infinite chain of `constructor` - `prototype`?

I mean which are the purpose of this chain and why there is no end, the prototype has a constructor and the constructor has a prototype, its a loop-chain, and the constructor everytime is the same, can't imagine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, every *Function Object*, by default has a `.prototype` property, which references the prototype object for this function (becomes only important if used as *constructor*).

And every `prototype object` by default has a reference to the `constructor` function, which of course, points back, to the constructor function (in your case `Test()`).

So, here we go

```
Test.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor
```

Comment: hmmm also the prototype.constructor.constructor.constructor. - works, incredible, still trying to understand...thanks

Comment: @Hello if you watch the `.prototype.constructor.constructor` carefully, you'll notice that this references the `Function()` basic constructor. Remember, a function is also an *object* in this language.

Answer (score 0):

This is a desired behavior. 
The `constructor` property of a prototype refers to the object that owns the prototype (so it refers back to itself).