# Constructor property : __proto__.constructor vs prototype.constructor

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototype-chain

I am fairly new to Javascript and I am trying to dig deep and understand inheritance, constructor functions and prototype chain.
So, I created a constructor function as such,

```
var a = function(){this.integer=1,this.float=1.0,this.string="one"}
```

Now, this function has a prototype.constructor property, a constructor property and a `__proto__.constructor` property.

I understand that the `__proto__.constructor` == the constructor function executed to create the function a. 
Also, the prototype.constructor is the function that is executed when I create an instance of 'a' using the new keyword.

However I don't understand what the third constructor property is for. Its equal to `__proto__.constructor`.

Also, `b.__proto__.constructor` !== `Object.prototype.constructor`, as I thought it would be. Why is that ?

Comment: You may find this useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221146/javascript-prototype-constructor-confusion

Comment: `a.constructor` actually is the inherited `a.__proto__.constructor` property

Comment: Ok makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a.__proto__` is the `Function` prototype (namely, `Function.prototype`). It is the object from which all functions inherit function-specific methods like `call`, `apply`, `bind`, etc. It is true that `a.__proto__.bind == a.bind`.

`a.__proto__.constructor` is the `Function` constructor, i.e., the function `Function`. The `Function` prototype has a reference to its associated constructor via the `constructor` property, as is always the default relationship between prototype object and constructor. (More on this "default relationship" in the next two paragraphs.)

Quite different is `a.prototype` -- in JavaScript, any function can be a constructor, i.e., it may be called with `new`. Whenever a function is called with `new`, it creates a new object whose `__proto__` is the function's `prototype` and points to the newly-created object via `this`. So inside a call to `new a()` it is true that `this.__proto__` equals `a.prototype`. This prototype object is automatically created and stored in `a.prototype` at the moment the function `a` is defined.

`a.prototype.constructor` is equal to `a`, because the JavaScript internal routine that creates `prototype` objects for newly-defined functions (as specified in the previous paragraph) always gives that new prototype a `constructor` property that refers to the newly-defined function. To get really into the weeds, the relevant ECMAScript routine is [19.2.1.1.1, CreateDynamicFunction](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-createdynamicfunction), which notes, "A `prototype` property is automatically created for every function created using CreateDynamicFunction, to provide for the possibility that the function will be used as a constructor."

`a` does not have its own `constructor` property, but it automatically inherits `a.__proto__.constructor` accessible as `a.constructor`, just as it inherits any other properties on its prototype parent (just like `a.bind` is really `a.__proto__.bind`).

Finally, `a.__proto__.constructor !== Object.prototype.constructor` because `Object.prototype` is not a function object's prototypal parent, but instead `Function.prototype` is. It is instead true that `a.__proto__.constructor === Function.prototype.constructor` (and, more succinctly, `a.__proto__ == Function.prototype` and `a.__proto__.constructor == Function`).

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful !!